# Why does segmasker modify headers?

Tags: phylogenetics, segmasker

When parsing [*NCBI BLAST+ segmasker*](https://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/repository/display_tool?repository_id=1d92ebdf7e8d466c&tool_config=%2Fsrv%2Ftoolshed-repos%2Fmain%2F000%2Frepo_241%2Ftools%2Fncbi_blast_plus%2Fncbi_segmasker_wrapper.xml&changeset_revision=5edc472ec434) output, I realized the program modifies almost every header containing these strings: `(`  or  `)` for no (known to me) reason.

In the majority of the strings mentioned above, the whitespace is removed:

- input file:
  `>tr|Q9UXV4|Q9UXV4_PYRAB Pyruvate formate-lyase activating enzyme ( act-1) OS=Pyrococcus abyssi (strain GE5 / Orsay) OX=272844 GN=act-1 PE=4 SV=1`,
  output file:
  `>tr|Q9UXV4|Q9UXV4_PYRAB Pyruvate formate-lyase activating enzyme (act-1) OS=Pyrococcus abyssi (strain GE5 / Orsay) OX=272844 GN=act-1 PE=4 SV=1`,
- input file:
  `>tr|A0A5K1JWI6|A0A5K1JWI6_9APHY Cysteine protease ATG4 ) OS=Ganoderma boninense OX=34458 GN=Q523C3 PE=4 SV=1`,
  output file:
  `>tr|A0A5K1JWI6|A0A5K1JWI6_9APHY Cysteine protease ATG4) OS=Ganoderma boninense OX=34458 GN=Q523C3 PE=4 SV=1`.

It isn't a significant change, but it complicates searching for headers in the output file.

However, the program is not consistent - if there is a comma (`,`) before the  `)` string, the whitespace is not removed:

- input file:
  `>tr|A0A3M9YA12|A0A3M9YA12_9PEZI Myeloid lymphoid or mixed-lineage leukemia 5 (Trithorax, ) OS=Verticillium nonalfalfae OX=1051616 GN=MLL5 PE=4 SV=1`,
  output file:
  `>tr|A0A3M9YA12|A0A3M9YA12_9PEZI Myeloid lymphoid or mixed-lineage leukemia 5 (Trithorax, ) OS=Verticillium nonalfalfae OX=1051616 GN=MLL5 PE=4 SV=1`.

What's the reason for such a behaviour?
Is there any option to prevent it and keep headers unchanged?

---

edit.
The whitespace is also removed for:

- →  ,
- `,` → `,`.

Moreover, it removes a semicolon when it is at the end of a header:
`>ABCD/1-4 ABCD;ABCD;` → `>ABCD/1-4 ABCD;ABCD`.

Comment: Weird... You could always run your input through something like `sed 's/ *)/)/g; s/( */(/g'` to remove the spaces yourself before using segmasker, but obviously that isn't ideal.